# AdMob works in testing and builds through Test Flight but not from the App Store?

Tags: ios, admob, testflight, iosdeployment

Currently my app renders AdMob adverts in simulator (test adverts) and adverts in TestFlight (real adverts) perfectly fine. However when I've downloaded my app from the App Store the adverts don't appear. It's hard to debug because I can't see the logs.

Anyone have any idea what might cause this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So for anyone that finds this issue my solution was:

I queried the App Store receipt list and checked the entries in that dictionary. If it contained a value (my app only has one IAP) then remove the adverts within the app. I thought the dictionary was unique to each app, turns out its not and it's shared.

TestFlight accounts didn't contain any entries so adverts were visible. Same with simulator.